# Casting a String to another type as a parameter of a method in Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I am trying to pass a value to a method by means of reflection in Java.

Namely, say we have string

```
String value = (some string representation of a value of type Type);
```

Say, we have a class with no-args-contructor, a single field `int field` and a single method, a setter method `setTheField`:

```
public class SomeClass{
    private SomeType field;

    SomeClass(){};

    public void setTheField(SomeType parameter){
        this.field = parameter
    }
}
```

where  `SomeType` of `field` may be primitive, wrapper or `LocalDate` / `LocalDateTime`.

If I take the setter (say):

```
Method setter = SomeClass.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()[0];
```

and then find out its parameters (say):

```
parametersList = Arrays.stream(setter.getParameters())
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then if check if the setter requires a single parameter:

```
if (parametersList.size() != 1) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Setter named = " +
            setter.getName() +
            " is not a single parameter setter!");
}
```

What I really want to do then, is to pass `string` to 'setter' on some object `SomeClass object = new SomeClass();` as `setter.invoke(object, value);` and I need somehow to cats `String value` to `SomeType` but I can not figure out how to do it uniformly.

Though, it seems a standard situation to appear and I hope someone more enlightened then me in Java can quickly figure out what to do.

Any suggestions are welcome.

**Addendum:**

I elaborate some more here.
The task I am trying to do is the following. Suppose I have an annotations `@Column{String name}` targeted to methods (or fields). Suppose I also have some domain class `SomeClass` with some setters (fields) annotated as `@Column`. I have to read from CSV top row with column names (headers to link data to the annotation's name), then I have to return a list of objects of my domain class `SomeClass`. This is the reason I am using reflection and I see no other way around.

Comment: String already is Object, and you can get the parameter types by calling method.getParameterTypes(), but as far as I know it is not neccessary, it the type is ok, then it should be ok, what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context this looks like a design problem. Why go through all the work to grab a setter by reflection and given a `String`, get a value compatible with the setter argument's type? If there's no other way around this problem, it is not possible to just cast a `String` to some other type. One possibility is making a factory class.

Assumption: the setter's argument type is some class called `MyType`.

```
class ArgumentFactory {
    MyType valueFor(String in) {
        // based on the string's value, put the conversion logic here
        if (in == null || in.isEmpty()) {
            return new MyType();
        }
        // add other cases as necessary ...
    }
}
```

Then you have

```
ArgumentFactory factory = new ArgumentFactory();
// ...
String value = "qwerty";
setter.invoke(object, argumentFactory.valueFor(value));
```

Comment: I have added some context in the text of the question.

Comment: Ok, since noone suggests other ways to do what I want, I accept this particular answer. It seems `ArgumentFactory`-like method is inevitable.